# Spread operator not showing type errors?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my React component, if i do this:

```
<MyComponent />
```

I get an error if i don't provide the `name` prop since it's required in `MyComponent`'s type. However, if i do this:

```
const emptyObj = {};
<MyComponent {...emptyObj} />
```

I don't get that error. Why is that?
Looking at other posts, i saw that it's related to excess properties?

> Excess property checking is when Typescript checks your object to
> ensure that it doesn't contain any extra properties on top of what is
> defined in the type annotation for the object.

So i'm not sure how that's related?

Comment: I expect that TS is inferring `emptyObj` to have an `any` type. I think if you spread an `any` typed object you're going to satisfy whatever typing you've specified on the consumer, since `any` is basically an escape hatch from TypeScript.

Comment: Since `{}` and `Object` is basically a non-nullish `any` (described as "any non-nullish value") you should add a rule against its usage with https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ban-types/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSX.IntrinsicElements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#attribute-type-checking)

Docs example:

```
declare namespace JSX {
  interface IntrinsicElements {
    foo: { bar?: boolean };
  }
}

const props = { requiredProp: "bar" };
<foo {...props} />; // ok
const badProps = {};
<foo {...badProps} />; // error
```

Comment: It was my first thought, as it helped with, for example, Window namespace types. Decided to double-check it, and it turned out that React without any additions should mark this types of errors. When I use example above, I get `Property 'bar' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ bar: string; }'.` You should probably make sure that `name` is required and maybe share `tsconfig.json` here